# List Sorting containing multiple values

Tags: tcl

I have a list List1 which I need to sort according to certain inet values.

```
proc compare {a b} {
set L1 [ ]  #Where L1 contain inet0 
set L2 [ ]  # Where L2 contain inet15
.
.
.
}

set sortedList [ lsort -command compare List1]
```

List1 here reference to certain inet values which are matter of interest here,

```
inet15  23726
inet0    23725
inet1   23727
inet31  23724
inet47  23720
inet5   23715
inet6   23727
```

process should return sorted List1 according to sorted inet.... such as. I am using older version of tcl.

```
inet0   23725
inet1   23727
inet2   23758
inet5   23715
inet15  23726
inet31  23724
```

Comment: Can you provide the contents of List1 and List2 and the expected output? From what's available above, I couldn't find a pattern in the left or the right column.

Comment: Like this is a list1 23726 23725 23727 23724 23720 23715 23727, and I have created a proc which should return sorted list1, so in this proc I extract net values using certain api. so 23726 inet15 ... and so on in above first list.
So procedure will sort list1 according to inet0, inet1 values. At the end I will have list1 sorted by according to the inet names which at the end will look like: 
inet0   23725
inet1   23727
inet2   23758
inet5   23715
inet15  23726
inet31  23724

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make use of the `-dictionary` option in `lsort` command.

```
set input "inet15 ﻿ inet0 ﻿ inet1 ﻿ inet31 ﻿ inet47 ﻿ inet5 ﻿ inet6 ﻿ inet7 ﻿ inet8 ﻿ inet9 ﻿ inet10 ﻿ inet11 ﻿ inet32 ﻿ inet13 ﻿ inet14 ﻿ inet2 ﻿ inet16 ﻿ inet17 ﻿ inet18 ﻿ inet20 ﻿ inet19 ﻿ inet21 ﻿ inet22"
puts [lsort -dictionary $input]
```

**Output :**

```
inet0 inet1 inet2 inet5 inet6 inet7 inet8 inet9 inet10 inet11 inet13 inet14 inet15 inet16 inet17 inet18 inet19 inet20 inet21 inet22 inet31 inet32 inet47
```

Once you have this list, you can simply get the mapping from the other list.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way with that data is to use the `-stride` and `-index` options to `lsearch`. `-stride` splits the list up into sublists that are sorted as units, and `-index` is used to select which item in a sublist is the collation key. Finally, the `-dictionary` option does exactly the kind of sort over the keys that you are looking for (it treats letter sequences and embedded numbers as special things).

```
set sortedList [lsearch -stride 2 -index 0 -dictionary $List1]
```

*However,* you also appear to want to retain the newlines. That's possible, but calls for slightly different processing.

```
# Split by newlines; in your case, we'll get a two-level list structure
set intermediate [split $List1 "\n"]
# Do the sort; don't need -stride as we already have the structure
set intermediate [lsearch -index 0 -dictionary $intermediate]
# Recombine to get newlines
set sortedList [join $intermediate "\n"]
```

Conversion to a one-liner is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I am using older version 8.4

Answer (score 0):

It's not evident what's list contents are. Here's a one approach where an array contains keys as elements from List1 and values from List2.
You can then iterate over sorted list of array elements and get the sorted output, per your example above.

```
sharad@ss:~$ cat my.tcl 
array set foo {
    inet15  23726
    inet0   23725
    inet1   23727
    inet31  23724
    inet47  23720
    inet5   23715
    inet6   23727
}

foreach inet [lsort -dictionary [array names foo]] \
{
    set value $foo($inet)
    puts $inet=$value
}
sharad@ss:~$ 

Output:
sharad@ss:~$ tclsh my.tcl
inet0=23725
inet1=23727
inet5=23715
inet6=23727
inet15=23726
inet31=23724
inet47=23720
sharad@ss:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
proc sortit { anum bnum } {
    set aname [zapper::extractname $anum]
    set bname [zapper::extract name $bnum]
    set sortnames [lsort -dictionary [list $aname $bname]]
    if { [ index $sortnames 0 ] != $aname } {
        return -1} else { 
           return 1 
         }
     return [list sortie [ lindex $anum 0] [ lindex $bnum 0 ]]
    }
```

called this using:

```
lsort -command sortit $List1
```